# jquery orgChart with multiple roots

Tags: jquery, orgchart

I am using this plugin https://github.com/caprica/jquery-orgchart to display all users from ActiveDidrectory. Problem is the structure is not correct.
So I need to display the tree(s) as it is to be able to fix it later. So I need to display multiple trees on the page.

```
$("#chart").orgChart({
                data: $.post(JSON from the server)
                });
```

This gives me the following error

> TypeError: rootNodes[0] is undefined $container.empty().append(rootNodes[0].render(opts));

Any ideas will be useful and appreciated. Thanks

P.S. The data I retrieve comes in proper format, tested minified version of it. Problem comes when there r multiple root="0"

Answer (score 0):

See `jquery.post()` is a async request so it does not wait for results, that is why it seems to create issue.

I guess you need to do it this way:

```
$.post("your/url/here", {data:"to send here"}, function(data){
    $("#chart").orgChart({ data:data });
});
```

Initialize the chart when you have the data to create chart.

Comment: That was my first try actually but bring only the first element which happens to have parent 0. It doesnot continue with the second which also has parent 0 btw.

Comment: @sis sorry can't get you on this.